# Help with solving limits

Tags: calculus, limits

Solve the following limits:

$$\lim _{x \to 3} \frac{1 - \sqrt{x-2}}{x^2 - 9} \quad \quad \text{and} \quad \quad \lim _{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{x^2-3}{x^2 + 7}\right)^{x^2 + x}$$

---

I'm relatively new to limits, but I managed to make some progress. Actually I solved the first limit, and conlcude that:

$$\lim _{x \to 3} \frac{1 - \sqrt{x-2}}{x^2 - 9} = -\frac{1}{12}$$

But I used L'Hopital Rule. Since L'Hopital Rule isn't allowed, is there any other way to solve it.

For the second one I managed to transform it to:

$$\lim _{x \to \infty} \left(1 - \frac{10}{x^2 + 7}\right)^{x^2 + x}$$

So i suspect the limit is:$\frac 1{e^{10}}$, because it looks very simular to the limit form for $e$ and I think it's due to the fact that $x^2 + x$ and $x^2 + 7$ grow simularly. But is there any better way to prove it, rather than just intuition.

P.S. I forgot to mention, but Taylor's Exapnsion is also not allowed.

Comment: Is L'Hospitals's rule allowed for the second one?

Comment: For both, an alternative to L'Hospitals is graphing it.

Comment: @voldemort No, L'Hopital isn't allowed for both of them. Second I think I'm on the right way with the second one, but is there any way to prove it?

Comment: With the second one, it sounds like you're allowed to use the fact that $(1+\frac{a}{x})^x \to e^a$ as $x \to \infty$. Is that right?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the second one, note that:

$\log \left[\left(\dfrac{x^2-3}{x^2+7}\right)^{x^2+x}\right] = \dfrac{x^2+x}{x^2+7}\log\left (1 - \dfrac{10}{x^2+7}\right)^{x^2+7}$

Take the limit for each term in the product (using the continuity of $\log$ and the standard $e$ limit you refer to in your original post) and then exponentiate to obtain:

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\dfrac{x^2-3}{x^2+7}\right)^{x^2+x} = e^{-10}$

Comment: One of my math professors always told me "If you want something to appear in a formula, just put it there." I think this is a perfect example of that!

Answer (score 3):

For the first one, try multiplying by $\frac{1+\sqrt{x-2}}{1+\sqrt{x-2}}$ and then simplifying the resulting expression.

Answer (score 2):

For the first limit, you can rationalize the numerator by multiplying the fraction by $\dfrac{1+\sqrt{x-2}}{1+\sqrt{x-2}}$.

For the second limit, you have the correct answer. Other than l'Hopital's rule, I think you are left with your intuition, graphing, or evaluating lots of values of $x$ that grow larger to see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answers give a good way to find the first limit, and I think you can find the second one by writing

$\big(\frac{x^2-3}{x^2+7}\big)^{x^2+x}=\bigg(\big(1-\frac{10}{x^2+7}\big)^{x^2+7}\bigg)^{\frac{1+\frac{1}{x}}{1+\frac{7}{x^2}}}\rightarrow \big(e^{-10}\big)^1=e^{-10}$